# How to Programmatically Reroute all TCP/IP or HTTP Connections from a Specific Process

Tags: macos, routes, network-programming, tcp

This is a pretty advanced question, and the answer likely involves some system and socket-level coding (which I'm not adverse to) as there appears to be nothing off the shelf that does this today. I'm open to all solutions (off-the-shelf or build-it-yourself.) Please provide your best advice.

I'm building a test execution environment that executes test binaries submitted by third-parties. The test binaries are built against a well-intentioned test framework which connects to an HTTP server for relaying of test commands and test results between browsers and virtual devices under test. This framework makes it easy for users to hard-code their tests to connect to a static IP address and port number, but provides no external override mechanism. The folks writing these test binaries are not always the sharpest tools in the shed, so asking them to do something as basic as taking dynamic IP addresses and port numbers is out of the question. It would add too much of a barrier to entry for this free service.

A single test binary needs to attach to exactly 1 browser/device host HTTP server available on the system (there will be dozens available on the system.) Only one test binary is allowed to connect to any specific browser/device host HTTP server at a time. I know from context associated with the binary which device they need to attach to. They'll try to attach to it by connecting to a default IP/port, where the default IP is localhost. At that point, I'd like a piece of software sitting there which routes connections on that port to a dynamic port based on the PID of the connecting process. That's magic, right? Based on the requesting process, actually connect them to a different port. Can this be done in user-mode? Is there some nifty utility server available which does this today?

Answers specific to Mac OS X (Lion) are preferred, but I'm happy to attempt to adapt any solution which works on other OS's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Linux based OS I recommend using a wrapper launcher to set the Type Of Service bits in all packets from the application. Then you can use an iptables rule to put all packets with that ToS bit in a chain and do whatever manipulation you need there. It should not require writing any software.

It's possible by using a preloading strategy to control access to system calls such as `socket` and set options on the socket. The Type Of Service is just a socket option. See [this paper](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix05/tech/freenix/full_papers/eriksen/eriksen.pdf) for an example of the strategy. I though I had used a userspace wrapper to do so in the past, but I can't find it now.

However I think a simpler approach exists possibly using iptables. The `owner` match target can match based on a number of paramters such as `uid`,`gid`,`pid`,`sid`, etc. It looks like on SMP kernels the `pid` and `sid` matching will not work and are thusly not present. At least on my Linux 3.2 kernel I am running they are not there. If you run your test binaries as a separate user that would still be an effective way to capture all packets from the test program and re route. You can capture them in the OUTPUT nat table and redirect them there to where ever with the DNAT target. Here's a hypothetical rule

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner softwaretesting -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
```

Here the user for running the tests is named `softwaretesting` and all IP traffic from programs launched by that user is redirect to 192.168.1.1. This probably has some unintended consequences like making `ssh` not really work for this user. Since you said the test framework is HTTP you could probably just match traffic for it by looking for port 80.

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m owner --uid-owner softwaretesting -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
```

Obviously if the HTTP is running on a nonstandard port you must adjust the `80` to be whatever port is in use.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! Would you be willing to provide additional guidance? I'm now struggling to figure out how to set the TOS bits in all packets from an application. I'm not finding anything after an hour of Google searches and looking on stackoverflow. I assume I would make some sort of system call to set this in the wrapper, then fork/exec? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a better more detailed strategy.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried charlesproxy (Mac) http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/ or Fiddler (Windows) http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Both allow rewrite of http connection.  I know Fiddler is scriptable, i believe Charles is as well, but haven't tried it

Comment: This is a bit advanced for Charles proxy (it doesn't offer any features resembling rerouting of traffic.) Fiddler does appear to keep track of the process which initiated a request, but does not appear to offer the ability to reroute connections either.